# Plex Media Manager won't find /media/Movies or /media/TV internal HDD

Tags: plex

When I do a search for media in each of these drives (which are loaded with movies and TV shows), Plex doesn't find anything. When I searched my music folder, it only found two artists (and I have at least 20).  I am fairly new to Ubuntu, and I am lost as to where to start. Any ideas? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had that at first, it was erratic.

Then I found that you have to follow their naming conventions (ish)

[Plex Media Naming Guide](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Media_Naming_and_Organization_Guide)

Mostly it's this:

```
Movies\
    MovieName (YEAR).extention
    MovieName (YEAR).extention

TV Shows\
    ShowName\
       Season 1\
          ShowName S01EXX.extention
```

Usually then it's easier to just delete the section out of Plex and re-add it.
If you want to force it to re-do just one show, go to the show in plexweb and click the Unmatch link then re-scan, that seems to (eventually) sort itself out.

Comment: Sadly neither following the Plex naming conventions or removing and re-adding sections helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding Plex to the plugdev group.**

Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

`sudo gpasswd -a plex plugdev`

Verify that plex was added to the plugdev group by entering:

`groups plex`

which should display what groups plex belongs too. Next, reboot the computer and start plex to verify this corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and Plex MediaServer 0.9.1107.

It was a problem with the permissions on the files and folders I copied across to the system. So if you right click on the folder (e.g. Movies) left click on properties. Select the permissions tab. And make sure the 3 drop down menus are set to read/write or read.

Then update the media server again. It should find the files (As long as they are named correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I followed [anonynous](https://askubuntu.com/users/173120/anonynous)'s instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293704/how-to-make-folders-seen-by-plex).

After this and making sure that all files that I wanted Plex to see were owned by my UserID and adding Plex to my Users Group I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that ALL of the files, songs and movies have their permissions set as shared to read and write

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution i tried: re-install linux (I use linux Mint) and when it gets to the naming part just name it "Plex" --- permissions problem solved (well for me it worked) and I am a noob to linux but really like the advances since my first exposure to linux. My first exposure was Think linux 5.0. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is that the correct path to your HDD?

Mine is, /media/username/media/Movies

---

Have you added permissions to your drive?

Use capitals or lowercase in directory(folder) names as linux does use these.

in terminal, copy and paste [shift + ctrl + v]

(after checking drive path you may need to edit the directory (dir)
e.g. /media/username/HDD name/folder name
also edit username to your username)

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /media/Movies/

sudo chmod -R 775 /media/TV/
```

this will change permissions for your users and groups to read, write and execute and for others to only read and execute.
DO NOT do chmod 777. It can be dangerous if you do not know what you are doing.

---

Next add your user to plex group

```
sudo usermod -a -G plex username
```

my plex after some work, works perfectly.
I too had the problem of plex not being able to see my second HDD.

Let me know if this worked, if not, Ill help you until you get it going.