# How to make folders ' seen' by PLEX

Tags: directory, plex

When I want to add a folder to PLEX I cannot find it.

I have 2 harddrives in my computer. Ubuntu 13 installed on the 120GB SSD and another 1TB normal harddrive which contains 1 Folder called 'Films'. In that folder there are many other folders with films in it.

When I add a Movie section from PLEX I can select the 1TB harddrive. So the drive is recognized. But afterwards I cannot select the folder 'Films' althoug it is there.

The filemanager (second icon from the top on menu bar) does show the folder.

Any clue how I can make sure PLEX recognizes this folder so I can select it?

Answer (score 22):

Here is my solution:

Remove the old installation of plex:

```
sudo apt-get remove plexmediaserver
sudo apt-get purge plexmediaserver
sudo rm -r plexmediaserver/
```

Download plex from the website

Go to Downloads folder

Install plex:

```
sudo dpkg -i plexmediaserver_0.9.7.22.511-4b5280f_amd64.deb
```

change user to you instead of plex:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver
```

Run once

```
http:// localhost:32400/web/index.html#!/dashboard
```

Stop:

```
sudo service plexmediaserver stop
```

add user to group:

```
sudo addgroup plex youruser
```

sudo addgroup youruser plex

start:

```
sudo service plexmediaserver start
```

Comment: A bit time confusing to add just one folder...

Comment: Thinks!! This is the simplest way I found to get Plex working!

Comment: The problem( plex is not running as the logged user on linux) is widely discussed. The obvious answer, how to change it to the desired one, and where is the location of the config file, is described in plain English, here and here only. Thanx!

Comment: Thank you! change user to you instead of plex: ```sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver```  This seemed to do it for me. I would love to figure out how to make it work with plex at the user though.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify the last few lines? Is 'sudo addgroup youruser plex' something you type as well? Do you do both `addgroup plex youruser` and `addgroup youruser plex`?

Comment: This enables me to use folders in home, but still doesn't allow me to access mounted drives in /media/myuser for some reason...

Comment: I like the "sudo rm -r plexmediaserver/" without expliciting in which folder. It's absolutely not obvious

Comment: The right way to go is make sure every relevant storage is mounted properly in /etc/fstab, so no root privileges will be required. This is discuessed here: https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/112804/plex-wont-read-folders-files-on-mounted-drive-in-linux-mint

Just auto-mounting for all users in /etc/fstab works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

This because plex does not support sub folders. What id did was copy all my movies out of their sub folders and into a new folder. Try executing the following commands

```
mkdir ~/PlexMovies
find ~/Videos -name '*.mp4' -exec cp {} ~/PlexMovies \;
```

Now this assumes that all your videos are in the mp4 format. Execute this command for every type of video you have by replacing `*.mp4` with any other movie type. Then have plex pull your movies from `~/PlexMovies`