# plex: how to add a local .mkv file to a library?

Tags: configuration, webserver, plex, mediaserver, mkv

Looking to play this `mkv` file:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tree /home/thufir/plex/
/home/thufir/plex/
└── The.Last.Dance.S01E01.HDTV.x264-BRISK[TGx]
    ├── [TGx]Downloaded from torrentgalaxy.to .txt
    ├── the.last.dance.s01e01.hdtv.x264-brisk.mkv
    └── the.last.dance.s01e01.hdtv.x264-brisk.nfo

1 directory, 3 files
thufir@dur:~$
```

from `plex`, so I changed the setting to the `Plex Video Files Scanner` as [suggested](https://forums.plex.tv/t/no-mkv-files-showing-up-at-all/78933/10):

[image: mkv]

However, when I click into the library:

[image: library]

I still get:

[image: lost]

> You must be lost 
>   We can't find the page you're looking for

perhaps just a permissions issue??

[Plex won't enter my home directory or other partitions](https://askubuntu.com/q/150909/45156)

but then why did `plex` navigate [to](https://askubuntu.com/q/293704/45156) the folder in question?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "last dance" gives:
[image: mj]

which just makes me wonder how to browse to the file in question rather than searching by title.

Answer (score 0):

I just need some more info.
Does the file, the last dance, play through plex?
Do you have any other media that works okay, or does nothing show up without searching?
Have you done any chown or chmod commands to your hdd or media folder through terminal?

I personally use plex movie for my scanner and my library shows up on an internal HDD, maybe change it back to that. Then ill get you as close to my config as possible and see if that helps you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).