# I cannot get Plex server to see any directories

Tags: permissions, plex

I have tried adding a directory outside my home directory.  /media/plex and soft linked my /Videos directory to it.

I have also added plex to udev group and also to my user group

```
uid=124(plex) gid=135(plex) groups=135(plex),46(plugdev),1000(marrabld)
```

and

```
uid=1000(marrabld) gid=1000(marrabld) groups=1000(marrabld),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),118(admin),124(sambashare),128(vboxusers),135(plex)
```

marrabld is my username.

the permissions on the softlink are

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 plex plex 4096 Apr 30 21:14 plex
```

But no mater where I tell plex to look, cannot see any directories in : /Videos ; /media/plex/* or any usb drives I plug in

If I sudo su plex I cannot see anything in my users home directory either.

The permissions in my Videos directory are

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

for all of them.

XBMC can see all of the files no problem.

I have tried the solutions here :

[Plex Media Manager won't find /media/Movies or /media/TV internal HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175453/plex-media-manager-wont-find-media-movies-or-media-tv-internal-hdd)

and

[Plex won't enter my home directory or other partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150909/plex-wont-enter-my-home-directory-or-other-partitions)

and a whole bunch of other places with no joy.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As per its default configuration, Plex uses the `Plex:Plex` user and group, and will have issues accessing directories if that user / group doesn't have the proper permissions to do so. To work around that problem (Ubuntu 23.04 Plex Vers. 4.108.0)

I created the override configuration file `sudo systemctl edit plexmediaserver`

Added the following lines to the start of the file,

```
[Service]
User=
User=<user>
Group=
Group=<group>
```

and saved it as `/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service.d/override.conf`

Now Plex will have access to the directories, but **will no longer have access to its own directory**...and will fail to start. So we need to change the owner of the Plex directory as well to the `<user>` and `<group>`

`sudo chown -R <username>:<group> /var/lib/plexmediaserver`

Finally run `sudo service plexmediaserver restart` to restart the service

and run `systemctl status plexmediaserver.service` to check its status.

Comment: @bobbie-e-ray Why do you leave 'User=' empty in one line and then write 'User=<user>' on the next line, and the same with 'Group='? Is there a specific reason for using two lines instead of just one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just plex can't find your files or find your directories?

I had a similar issue where plex just wouldn't find any of my files I had in my directories. The issue is likely due to the plex user not having the correct permissions.

Open this config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver
```

Find this line:

```
PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER = plex
```

Replace plex with your username, and save the file. Once I restarted my computer, Plex was able to access the folders on the external drive.

You may be able to run `sudo service plexmediaserver restart` instead of rebooting.

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Mounting NTFS Drives on Linux](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux):

1. Add `ntfs-3g permissions,auto` option to `/etc/fstab`. This will enable `chmod`.
2. `chmod` your folders/drives to `drwxr-xr-x`.

This helps with one remark; it didn't work till I got one thing: user (plex) can't get access to a folder if he can't get access to it's parent folder/mount point.

If you got your NTFS partition `/mnt/ntfs_partition` link, the above will work. But if you got `/media/%username%/ntfs_partition` you have to `chmod` not only `ntfs_partition` to `drwxr-xr-x`, but also `%username%` as well. In my case it was `drwxr-x---` so user plex was out.